# How to login/logout using mysql database and php session with or without AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, session, authentication, logout

I need a step by step tutorial for using PHP mechanism to login/logout using session, with or without AJAX as a client interface.

Using mysql database as the data model.

Thanks,
Damjan Dimitrioski.

Comment: Im not a fan of LMGTFY, but this one's good...

Answer (score -1):

There are many tutorials around to do similar processes, be it with plain php or with php frameworks. 
To avoid answering with links, I enclose instructions step by step to implement a database - session login/logout system with plain php. 
To allow the users to try by themselves, I list the steps instead of giving the full code. Still, I provide links to implementation examples, fully coded, at the bottom.

1. **Build your users table** with at least the following data:

   - id
   - username
   - password
2. To establish and check if the user is logged in, we will use one or two **$_SESSION variables**. A common option would be using the user id from the database. You can also have another variable registered: maybe the user name to greet them once they are logged, etc. Lets use **id and username** as an example.
3. Build a **login page with a username/password form** (html)
4. Write a method in **PHP to process the login form** (you can call it via ajax or at the form action). You also can write inline PHP code to do this if required.

   - start the session with session_start()
   - validate the username and password $_POST (ed) from the previous form
   - query the database for the given username and password:

     - If the **user exists, save the session variables** you stablished at step 2 (for our example, $_SESSION["id"])- Then redirect to the protected index.
     - If the **user does not exist, print a message** saying so.
5. Protect the content:
   write a method and use it to c**heck if a user is logged in or not before loading your content** like this:

   - start the session
   - if the **session variables are set, show the content**
   - if the session variables are **not set**, show a **link to the login** (or redirect the user there with header location, for example)
6. Provide a **Logout** page (or method to call it via ajax, for example)

   - start the session
   - unset each session variable you used at the user login
   - show the user a message or redirect to the login page/ any other action you wish to perform here

> Links to tutorials and code examples implementing the solution:
>
> - https://www.wdb24.com/session-in-php-example-for-login-logout/
> - https://www.w3tweaks.com/simple-php-login-and-logout-script-using-php-session-and-database-using-mysql.html